# dynamically include rails modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm using Ruby on Rails, and I want to know how to include a module, from modules that have the same name.

So, I have a ActiveRecord model called Course

it needs to include CourseModuleFactory depending on the course.level
There are 2 CourseModuleFactory modules both with the same name but in different folders.

So I need code something like this:

```
after_initialize :course_module_factory_level

def course_module_factory_level
  if self.level == "A"
    self.class.send(:include, CourseModuleFactory ) #from folder A
  else
    self.class.send(:include, CourseModuleFactory ) #from folder B
  end
end
```

This code would be in the Course model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without questioning your implementation, maybe you can use this:

```
def course_module_factory_level

  # will remove the module definition
  remove_const(CourseModuleFactory)

 if self.level == "A"
    # will reload the file and redefine the module. Note that require only loads once.
    load('./A/course_module.rb')
    self.class.send(:include, CourseModuleFactory)
  else
    load('./B/course_module_factory.rb')
    self.class.send(:include, CourseModuleFactory)
  end
end
```

Maybe you can try to find out a better design, like renaming these modules differently and avoid having  to redefine the same modules again and again